# Xamarin Forms - iOS debug on actual device hangs on launchscreen. Workin on simulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, storyboard, prism, appdelegate

I have a XF app already published on the play store and now I am targetting iOS. During developpent I made sure the app was still working on iOS, using the simulator only.

On the simulator everything works as expected, the launch screen is shown then the MainPage starts. But when I debug on an actual IPhone device, the app get stuck on the `Launchscreen.storyboard` for about 20 sec then the app exits. I've no debug output and it seems that the `AppDelegate` is never hit. Breakpoints in `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching` method are not hit for instance. I tried to F11 for start in debugging mode but I don't hit anything, still hanging on the launch screen. I was expecting the transition from simulator to device to be less painful.

My plist file contains the following permission requirements

```
...
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need to use your location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We are using your location</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery.</string>
```

The only difference I saw is that location permissions are not asked on the device while in the simulator it asks for it at start. But this might be related to the fact that I can't reach `AppDelegate`, I am not sure yet.

The iOS project was generated via Prism templates. I am using `VS 16.8.0 on Windows`, `XF 4.8.0.1687`, `Prism 8.0.0.1909`, `Xamarin iOS SDK 14.4.1.3` and I am set to "don't link" for linkers option. The device is an Iphone 10.

Any idea how can I find out the root cause - or get some useful logs?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

Here are the device log output during a new installation https://taits.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/devicelogs.txt. I am trying to go through them but kinda lost.

Comment: Can you check if there is any device log in the tools->iOS->Device log?

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! I've uploaded some logs. Hope the format is OK. For some reason I am able to get logs only during 1st launch after plugging the device. I tried to search for "error" and go through them but I am fairly lost.

Comment: Yes, there seems no exception in the log. Can you please try another device to check if the problem happens on specific device? Remember to clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: Sorry unfortunatly I don't have a second phone at the moment and it might takes some extra days to do such test. Meanwhile I tried a few other things, started a new project from scratch adding packages 1 by 1. The new solution is working on the device with the same set up. But I would like to avoid migrating everything to a new project. The big difference is I see permission missing in the phone app settings despite having them in the info.plist. The new solution doesn't have this problem, I think this might be related.

Comment: Actually I've found this: my shared project is referencing another custom project which in turn reference a nuget package causing this issue. I've found this by moving everything I needed from the referenced project into the shared project then started to reference packages from scratch 1by1 and clean/rebuild on the device for each of them. I will probably have to workaround this by finding an alternative way. Thanks for the help anyway. Not easy and pretty painful to spot.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You can also share the solution in the answer and mark it which may help more people with same problem:).